# tornadoFX togglebutton does not have text property

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I am new to kotlin and tornadoFX.
In TornadoFX Guide, a ToggleButton can be built with the following:

```
togglebutton("OFF").action { text = if (isSelected) "ON" else "OFF" }
```

But when I copy the same codes into my IDE, there's wrong!

[image: codes from guide copied to my IDE]

It seems that there's no text property in togglebutton in tornadoFX?

Answer (score 3):

It seems we were a bit eager to update the guide with the new `.action` syntax, so the example in the guide is actually wrong. The correct code would be:

```
togglebutton("OFF") {
    action {
        text = if (isSelected) "ON" else "OFF"
    }
}
```

The reason the example in the guide is wrong, is that when you call `togglebutton("OFF").action { .. }`, then `this` inside of `action {}` is actually the surrounding container instead of the button.

For actions that don't operate on the button itself, the short syntax is fine, but if you need to manipulate the button, you need to use the full syntax so your code executes in the context of the button.

On another note, it might be more idiomatic to create a stringbinding to represent the button state, instead of manually updating it in the action callback:

```
togglebutton {
    val stateText = selectedProperty().stringBinding {
        if (it == true) "ON" else "OFF"
    }
    textProperty().bind(stateText)
}
```

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Grateful for every reported issue and question :)